# How to eliminate a specific character string within a filename?

Tags: shell-script, rename

I have ripped a number of DVDs for a home HTPC (plex server).  Some of the file names contain unwanted characters.  I want to preserve most of the original filename string but eliminate the undesired text within it. Here are some examples:

- Existing Filename `Apollo 18-1.mp4`, remove `-1` New filename `Apollo 18.mp4` Rule: within a chosen directory find all filenames ending in "-1" and eliminate the character string "-1"
- Filename `ENTOURAGE_DISC1.Title1.avi`, remove `.Title1` New filename `ENTOURAGE_DISC1.avi` Rule: within a chosen directory find all filenames ending in ".Title1" and eliminate the character string ".Title1"

Comment: This question is not super clear.  How do you expect to choose what to remove and where?  I assume that `mv "Apollo 18-1.mp4" "Apollo 18.mp4"` is not what you are after.

Comment: Examples are okay, but you need to give exact rules like, because more than one rules could leed to your examples. For example: "If the filename has a dash and number right before the extension, remove dash and digits."

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`'s `zmv`, extrapolating the requirements from those 2 examples:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv '(*)(.Title<->|-<->).(mp4|avi)' '$1.$3'
```

`<->` is any sequence of decimal digits. (one form of `<x-y>` where neither boundaries are provided). If you only want `.Title1` and `-1` specifically and any extension, you can always change it to:

```
zmv '(*)(.Title|-)1(.[^.]##)' '$1$3'
```

`[^.]##` matching one or more non-dot characters.

Comment: I'm fairly computer literate but a novice in Linux.  I installed ZSH from the Linux Mint Package manager.  It appears to be installed successfully.  However, if I enter zsh at a cli prompt my prompt changes to this % and zmv is not recognized.  What may I have done wrong?

Comment: @GuyD'Amico, you need the `autoload zmv` (best in `~/.zshrc`) as indicated. You'll find a lot of information online to configure `zsh` to your taste.

Comment: I edited zshrc to include "autoload zmv" under a heading #autoload, then saved the file.  Then within the zsh-5.3.1 folder, at the shell prompt, I type ZSH and my prompt changes.  Entering zmv returns command not found. I'm obviously making rookie mistakes.

Comment: @Guy, Note that it's `~/.zshrc` (note the dot and it has to be in your home directory, not a `zshrc` file) your zsh customization file. You can also enter that `autoload zmv` at the prompt of that zsh shell.

Comment: I was not aware that the dot preceding zshrc indicated it was a hidden file.  So many details for a neophyte.  In any event, thanks for your help.  I should be good now.